# Extracting data from JSON with Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

I'm extracting data from a food recipe api and the response is JSON.

```
{
    "results": [
            {
                "id": 147605,
                "title": "Mac and Cheese",
                "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/147605-312x231.png",
                "imageType": "png"
             },
             {
                "id": 137592,
                "title": "Mac and Cheese",
                "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/137592-312x231.png",
                "imageType": "png"
             },
             {
                "id": 760335,
                "title": "Mac and Cheese",
                "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/760335-312x231.jpg",
                "imageType": "jpg"
             },
             {
                "id": 1047165,
                "title": "Mac and Cheese",
                "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/1047165-312x231.jpg",
                "imageType": "jpg"
             }
         ],
         "offset": 0,
         "number": 4,
         "totalResults": 1171
}
```

I want to extract the title, id, and image.
I did:

```
request(url, (error, response) => {
    console.log(response.body.results["id"])
    console.log(response.body.results["title"])
    console.log(response.body.results["image"])
})
```

I will want to store them in variables and do other stuff with it, but for now I just want to print it out to the terminal.

I'm getting undefined for all the logs.
I'm not sure if I should be doing some sort of loop, or something of that nature.

I should also add, when I do:

```
    console.log(response.body.results) // outputs undefined
    console.log(response.body)         // outputs the JSON response
```

So this must mean I'm accessing the results array incorrectly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to parse the response.body using **JSON.parse(response.body)** and assign the result to a variable. Now you should be able to access the data. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: PS: Request Is deprecated, use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead

Comment: See @DaStrangeBoi answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```js
response.body.results["id"]
```

You're saying that `results` is a object when its not an object but instead an array of objects. That being said if you want to access the first object you will have to call it like

```js
console.log(response.body.results[0].id);
```

and you can put that in a loop if you're trying to get all of them

```js
for (let i = 0; i < response.body.results.length; i++) {
    console.log(response.body.results[i].id)
}
```

### **Edit:**

One thing I failed to see is that `response.body.results` returns undefined. as @Carlo Corradini said `JSON.parse(response.body)` might solve that issue.

An example would be:

```js
let jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
console.log(jsonData.results[0].id);
```

Hopefully this helps! sorry if this got confusing. if so just ask any question you have